# Azure ML Studio - adding new column

Tags: azure, machine-learning, data-modeling

Do you know which module in Azure Machine Learning Studio allow to add new column? I do not mean'copy-paste' column from different data set, but new column, based on given logic, e.g. IF statement? I suppose that one way is just to execute custom R/Python script, but is there any dedicated module?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module `Execute Python Script` using Panda's `DataFrame` manipulation:

```
import pandas as pd

# The entry point function can contain up to two input arguments:
#   Param<dataframe1>: a pandas.DataFrame
#   Param<dataframe2>: a pandas.DataFrame
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    # Execution logic goes here
    print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))


    dataframe1['new_column'] = dataframe1.apply(lambda row: extractValue(row), axis=1)

    # Return value must be of a sequence of pandas.DataFrame
    return dataframe1,


def extractValue(row):
    return 1 if row['column1'] == 'something else 2
```

You can also use the `Execute Python Script` to create a new dataset with new columns and use the `Add Columns` module to merge them.

Answer (score -1):

"Apply Math Operation" is the module,
as well as "Apply SQL Transformation" module.

set Output mode = Append

Comment: This doesn't work since you need to select an EXISTING column for the output.